# redirect from landing page after another page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my question about redirect from landing page after another page loaded
i have two pages landing.html and index.html
i need to redirect from landing page after 5 seconds
so i use refresh meta

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=index.html" />
```

i also uses javascritp loading in case of old browsers

```
<script>
        var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            window.location='index.html'
        }, 5000);
    </script>
```

i need index.html to began loading when the user open landing.html
so after the user redirect to index.html, he will find its loaded

Comment: Its not a way to do things like this in client server architecture. I suggest you to add a load icon when page is not ready and when it is show the page.

Comment: i already added load icon, it's mobile application so i need to reduce load time if user network is weak

Comment: You could try loading index.html into a hidden iframe, or its content (via AJAX) if on the same domain) into a hidden div, and then rely on the client cache to load most the elements from cache when the href changes.

Comment: very goooood idea, thanks (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an Ajax function to load up a hidden div, and rely on the browser cache.  You then have the option of re-directing after a set time, or adding the re-direct to the `load` callback:

```
HTML:
<div id = "hidden" style = "display:none"></div>

JS
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#hidden').load('index.html');
      setTimeout(function() {
         location.href = 'index.html';
      }, 5000);
   });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hidden').load('index.html', function() {
        location.href = 'index.html';
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your snippet is the fact, that you first request landing page, then wait for 5 seconds, and just then request index.html - which starts loading after the 5 seconds, leaving the user loading 2 pages with 5 seconds delay.

### 1 Possible solution would be this:

Request Index.html on landing page via ajax and display it after the ajax has loaded the index.html

The code would look something like this:

### landing.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">

    <head>
        <title>LENDING PAGE</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="frontend.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>LANDING PAGE CONTENT</body>

</html>
```

### frontend.js

```
$.ajax({

    url: '/sandbox/index.html',
    dataType: 'html'

}).done(function(html, status_text, response) {

    if(response.status === 200) {

        document.write(html)

    } else {

        // html couldnt be loaded, hendle error

    }
}).fail(function(err) {

    // error during jQuery ajax

});
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>INDEX PAGE</title>        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body> INDEX PAGE CONTENT </body>

</html>
```

There is, however 1 problem with this solution. The JS replaces the document with HTML of index.html, but all the external files (i.e. CSS), will have to be loaded anyway.

### BETTER SOLUTION

If the landing page isn't very complicated, put it in a div with fixed position over whole page and when the page has finished loading, hide the landing div.

```
// hide landing div on document.ready
$(function() {
    $('#landing_div').hide();
})
```